# Broken elevation shadow during animation on Android Pie

Tags: android

I am experiencing weird shadow behavior, when animation of parent viewGroup is taking place on Android Pie. It is happening on all phones with android 9.0 I have. Except for emulator.
So, the shadow is blinking and kinda offset.

To simulate, I have this simple Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.animated_item).startAnimation(AlphaAnimation(0.9f, 1.0f).apply {
            duration = 500
            repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
            repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
        })
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="6dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/animated_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="6dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably, it's too late, but to get rid of this effect I had to apply animation to the View with elevation itself, but not to its parent layout.